# DownloadFile vs DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, networking, webclient

I'm using WebClient.DownloadFile to download a single file at a time from a web server, however, I want to know if by "The thread is blocked" developers mean that the application won't be responsive?

I tried using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync but it doesn't work like DownloadFile works, please clarify, and I can't tell because I'm downloading files off my network, so it pretty much downloads instantly, thanks in advance.

PS: Yes I tried googling and reading, couldn't find the answer I need.

Comment: Unfortunately, with VS2010 you cannot use `async/await` and [`Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) (which offers an improved [`DownloadFileTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159424(v=vs.110).aspx) API). Nevertheless, you still can use [EAP-to-Task pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/19/9791857.aspx) to make your code better structured.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` ends with "Async" but doesn't return a task. It's part of the `Event-based Asynchronous Pattern` so my answer isn't relevant. This one is: You need to subscribe to `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event to know when the async operation completed. For example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var uri = new Uri(address);

client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Finished");
client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "Hamsters.txt");
```

Original Answer:
`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` returns a task you need to await. like so:

```
await WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(...)
```

`DownloadFileAsync` is fires an asynchronous operation and returns a task that will complete when the operation ended. `await` means waiting for that task to end in an asynchronous way, so the code after it will run when you have the result of `DownloadFileAsync`.

The synchronic `DownloadFile` will block the thread that called it. If it's the UI thread, then yes... your app won't be responsive. If it isn't the UI thread, then it will still be responsive but it will be less scalable (meaning it uses threads to wait instead of doing work, so your application as a whole can do less with the same amount of threads)

Comment: I understand, I happen to be using VS 2010, apparently it doesn't support await, is there any other alternative?

Comment: Yes. several. You can use `async-await` with VS 2010 using BCL.Async. or you can register a continuation to the task with `ContinueWith`: `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(...).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine(_.Result);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've been looking for this answer for a couple of days, I'll try it right now :)

Comment: @user3157365 You can also use the `DownloadFileCompleted` event that occurs when an asynchronous file download operation completes.

Comment: I had tried that but it causes a lot of problems most of the time for some reason. I will study the .contiueWith tonight and apply it tomorrow, hopefully I'll get some better results, thanks again!

Comment: Your edit was relevant indeed, I edited your code a little and it worked like a charm, thanks again, great help to keep my little application going :)

Comment: @l3arnon, [`Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) cannot be used with VS2010. It's for VS2012 to target .NET 4.0. On a bright side, `Bcl.Async` does offer the new [`DownloadFileTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159424(v=vs.110).aspx) API, similar to what you original described in your answer.

Comment: Why is it returning `void`? is there any reason?

Answer (score 11):

```
client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), saveLocation).Wait();
// Waiting for download...
```

Comment: or await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), saveLocation);