# C# Download file after last file ends download

Tags: c#

I want to listed file download with WebClient
but WebClient it does not allow several actions at a time and this code calls all downloads at once but I want the file to be downloaded separately

modlist.txt

```
mod1.jar
mod2.jar
mod3.jar
mod4.jar
```

Code

```
private void DownloadingFiles()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(dir + "modlist.txt"))
            {
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(site + "modlist.txt"), dir + "modlist.txt");
            }
        }

        private void DownloadingMods()
        {
            var files = File.ReadAllLines(dir + "modlist.txt");
            foreach (var filename in files)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(dir + "mods/" + filename))
                {

                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(site + "mods/" + filename), dir + "mods/" + filename);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You would need to change your code completely and make it asynchronious.

Comment: If you specifically want them to be one by one, consider changing `DownloadFileAsync` to `DownloadFile`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DownloadFile vs DownloadFileAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009162/downloadfile-vs-downloadfileasync)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await` and `async` like:

```
private async Task DownloadingFiles()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(dir + "modlist.txt"))
        {
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(site + "modlist.txt"), dir + "modlist.txt");
        }
    }

    private async Task DownloadingMods()
    {
        var files = File.ReadAllLines(dir + "modlist.txt");
        foreach (var filename in files)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(dir + "mods/" + filename))
            {

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(site + "mods/" + filename), dir + "mods/" + filename);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` is a legacy non-`Task`-returning method. I believe what you were looking for is `DownloadFileTaskAsync`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, you are right, I have updated the answer. I am a bit confused why there is Async in the method name then.