# Wait till the last file is downloaded

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I have a code for downloading PDF files. Now I have run into a problem when I am executing next task but download of last file is not yet finished. After execution of my current code last file is something like 650 Mb and it should be 1300 Mb. Also it is not possible to open it as it is not fully downloaded and that's why broken.

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

How to ensure that files are downloaded?

```
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://example.com/");

            // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

            HtmlNodeCollection ProductListPage = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='productContain padb6']//div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']/a");
            foreach (HtmlNode src in ProductListPage)
            {
                htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(src.Attributes["href"].Value);

                // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                HtmlNodeCollection LinkTester = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='row padt6 padb4']//a");
                if (LinkTester != null)
                {
                    foreach (var dllink in LinkTester)
                    {
                        string LinkURL = dllink.Attributes["href"].Value;
                        Console.WriteLine(LinkURL);

                        string ExtractFilename = LinkURL.Substring(LinkURL.LastIndexOf("/"));
                        var DLClient = new WebClient();

                        // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                        DLClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
                    }
                }
            }
```

My next process is to rename downloaded files:

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.pdf");
    // string prefix = "SomePrefix";
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string newFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), file.Replace("-", " "));
        File.Move(file, newFileName);
    }
```

Renaming goes smooth until last file that is not completely downloaded and that's where I am getting an error.

I have added `Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time` between these two, but that's maybe not the best solution as current waiting time is not enough and it can change according to internet connection?

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace Crawler
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            {
                HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://example.com");

                // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                HtmlNodeCollection ProductListPage = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='productContain padb6']//div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']/a");
                foreach (HtmlNode src in ProductListPage)
                {
                    htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(src.Attributes["href"].Value);

                    // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                    HtmlNodeCollection LinkTester = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='row padt6 padb4']//a");
                    if (LinkTester != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var dllink in LinkTester)
                        {
                            string LinkURL = dllink.Attributes["href"].Value;
                            Console.WriteLine(LinkURL);

                            string ExtractFilename = LinkURL.Substring(LinkURL.LastIndexOf("/"));
                            var DLClient = new WebClient();

                            // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                            DLClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.pdf");
            // string prefix = "SomePrefix";
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string newFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), file.Replace("-", " "));
                File.Move(file, newFileName);
            }


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: ```Downloads, to a local file, the resource with the specified URI. This method does not block the calling thread.``` according to MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=netframework-4.8). [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009162/downloadfile-vs-downloadfileasync) previous post should help you

Comment: Side note: its 2020 now... using `await` and `WhenAll` is be sooooo much easier that writing and managing callbacks...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DownloadFile vs DownloadFileAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009162/downloadfile-vs-downloadfileasync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly do not want to use `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` but its newer successor [`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=netframework-4.8). This would be used like this:

```
await DLClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
```

This is an `async` process, so your calling method will need to be `async` as well. By `await`ing it, you make sure that your program continues only after the download is complete (or has failed).

Comment: Hmm... thanks for that, but now it says `'WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadFileAsyncTask' and no accessible extension method 'DownloadFileAsyncTask' accepting a first argument of type 'WebClient' could be found`

Comment: Oh, I had a typo there: It should be `DownloadFileTaskAsync` not `DownloadFileAsyncTask`. Will update that.

Comment: My project in "Project Properties -> Application Tab" says Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Yup, that's fine - I had an error in my answer. It's now correct.

Comment: Great! Now it works! Maybe you have some idea about this issue? I somehow think async/await will help to get page loaded to get `ProductListPage`. I have noticed on VPN connection page is loaded with a little delay in CHrome for example. So first page is loaded and then comes the content. Maybe this is the reason for error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628313/download-all-pdf-files-from-crawled-links

Answer (score 1):

You should load and download it asynchronously instead of blocking the current thread. When you do this it will release the thread to the caller and return back to the context only when the Load/DownLoad has been completed

```
 htmlDoc = await new HtmlWeb().LoadAsync(src.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

and

```
 await DLClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
```